# Find the difference between the max and min of a third column if the first two columns match of an Excel file

Tags: python, excel

Rather new to Python and so far I've only done the very basics in an intro to python class. I was handed this data set and thought it could very easily be handled in python but I have no idea where to begin.

I have a 3 column table in excel. First column is a code, second column is a row number, and third column is a numeric value. If the first and second column combined are unique, that is if the first column is FLD04 and the second column is 1, then I want to find the difference + 1 between the max and min value in the 3rd column and print a line that reads FLD04 1 30 (30 being the result of the difference between the max and min + 1). And iterate this over and over for every instance where the first and second column together are unique.
IDK I can't figure out how to past the excel info as anything but an image. Sorry. Just wanted to post it to help illustrate what I am dealing with

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTQZY.png)

Comment: A first step would be to save the file as a .CSV file and load it into a pandas DataFrame (https://pandas.pydata.org/). From there you could start implementing your custom logic

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Sorry Nicolas, should have been more clear. I got that far. I already had pandas installed and imported the CSV into PyCharm. The code itself is where I'm completely stuck

Comment: "no idea where to begin." begin with (following any tutorial u refer to) : [ read excel file ] > export to an array / dataframe > [ export to a file ] || If THAT is successful, then only think about value manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

When I first learn Python, I like to print out those intermediate variables and see how they look. You may try the following code out, but change "Column#1,2,3" into the right names.

```
data = pd.read_excel(...) # Read your data: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

max = data.groupby(["CODE", "ROW"])["NUMBER"].max() #Group data by the first 2 columns, and for each group, find the maximum value in column 3

min = data.groupby(["CODE", "ROW"])["NUMBER"].min() #Get minimums

result = max - min + 1

print(result)
```